# Pricing criteria of AWS amplify using Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am confused about pricking criteria in aws amplify

Let's assume

```
List<Object> obj = Amplify.DataStore.query(Object.classtype, where: Object.ID.eq('123'));
//obj.length is 1000
```

Is this command 1000 requests or 1 request?

Answer (score 0):

There is no additional charges to use Amplify DataStore in your application, you only pay for the backend resources you use, such as AppSync and DynamoDB

Refer to DynamoDB pricing for your AWS region